# Running powershell from azure startup task

Tags: azure

In my ServiceDefinition.csdef file I have this:

```
 <Startup>
      <Task commandLine="powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -command &quot;Install-WindowsFeature Net-Framework-Core&quot;" taskType="simple" executionContext="elevated"/>
 </Startup>
```

But when I try to publish it to azure I get:

```
Cannot find file named 'approot\bin\powershell' for startup task powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -command "Install-WindowsFeature Net-Framework-Core"  of role WebRole.
```

I'm trying to run powershell so I can install .net 3.5 is OS family "3" (windows 2012). That command runs fine from a cmd line while remoted into my instance.

What's the correct syntax to run powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work with some help from Michael Volodarsky.

1. create a file called "install35.cmd" in the "Startup" folder:

powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -command "Install-WindowsFeature Net-Framework-Core"
exit 0

1. Save as / advanced / set codepage to windows 1252
2. In solution explorer, right click and set build type=content, copy always
3. In startup tasks, add: